# How to check array if it contains a string with same text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays

How do you check an array if a string contains the same text? Example, I have `cards` array that I declare and I want to find how many have the same string like **clubs** in my array. I tried using `includes` using jquery and it returns a boolean function true or false. What should be done here? Will it possible to use the `find` method in the array? Please help.

It should alert that an array has 3 strings that has the same value like **clubs**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var cards = ["ace_of_clubs.png","2_of_clubs.png","3_of_clubs.png","ace_of_hearts.png"];

var f_string = cards.includes("clubs");
alert(f_string);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`string#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check for substring in your array of string.

```js
var cards = ["ace_of_clubs.png","2_of_clubs.png","3_of_clubs.png","ace_of_hearts.png"],
    f_string = cards.filter(card => card.includes("clubs"));
console.log(f_string);
```

ES5 Code

```js
var cards = ["ace_of_clubs.png", "2_of_clubs.png", "3_of_clubs.png", "ace_of_hearts.png"],
    f_string = cards.filter(function (card) {
    return card.includes("clubs");
});
console.log(f_string);
```

Comment: How do I use `f_string` variable in an if condition sir @Hassan Imam do I freely use this `if(f_string)` to check how many string that has a substring of `clubs`?

Comment: In case you want to check for length, use `f_string.length` in your if condition.